# Android video player library with a slow motion feature

Tags: android, video

I am trying to find a video player library that I can add to my Android App source that will allow the user to play the video at a slower speed, ideally adjustable by the user.

And I need also with this library to capture a photo from video once in a second and save it.

Comment: I suggest you to embed VLC lib to your app.I t provides slow motion feature built in.

Comment: Thanks! I will try VLC.